# stateful widget error, A constant constructor can't call a non-constant super constructor of 'State'

Tags: flutter, dart

here is my public git.
https://github.com/CrazyBunnyz/Sociominer_V2/
there are 2 branches on that git.
the main is my original code with stateless for most of the part. the problem comes when I try to integrate my code with ExpansionTile where I need state to detect on onExpansionChanged. i try to implement the example but I keep getting the error below. can anyone please help. you can see both code before and after the error from both branches.
[image]
ps : already tried ChatMember({Key? key, this.deviceScreenType}) : super(key: key); it pop other error.
[image]
the full issue can be found in https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/118311. can anyone help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use widget clsss instead of state class. Remove params from `ChatMember` and use widget class.

```dart
class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final DeviceScreenType? deviceScreenType;
  const MyStatefulWidget({super.key, this.deviceScreenType});

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => ChatMember();
}

class ChatMember extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
```

Now to access widget variable do,

```dart
Column(
  children: List.generate(
    members.length,
    (index) => MemberCard(
      member: members[index],
      deviceScreenType: widget.deviceScreenType, //this
    ),
  ),
),
```

Next issue is you are naming differently and it's confusing,

Your case

- `MyStatefulWidget` is a widget class
- `ChatMember` is  state class

You need to use `MyStatefulWidget` like,

```dart
Container(
  width: 400,
  child: MyStatefulWidget(deviceScreenType: deviceScreenType),
),
```

You can check the [pr](https://github.com/CrazyBunnyz/Sociominer_V2/pull/1)